# iTerm2 - Oh My zsh: color issue

Tags: macos, terminal, colors, zsh

I'm trying to setup iTerm2 with Oh My Zsh on MacOs 10.14.5. Everything works fine but I am facing **color issues**.

Below you can see what I am expecting and what I get:
[image: Expected on top. Actually on bottom.]

As you can see, my screen is hardly readable. I have this issue on all existing itermcolor profiles I loaded.

Does someone have any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: What is `PS1` set to? Try setting it as follows `export PS1="\u@\h \W\\$"` (the default) in `~/.bash_profile` and work from there to customise it.

Comment: @DavidPostill I cannot past the whole content of my PS1, but this is something like this: ${${_P9K_CLM::=$COLUMNS}+}${${COLUMNS::=1024}+}%b%k%f${${_P9K_IND::=${${ZLE_RPROMPT_INDENT:-1}/#-*/0}...